# Monitoring MySQl with Zabbix Agent

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I can't get every result from the Zabbix default Template App MySQL. The error is:

> Not supported by zabbix agent

I already setup `zabbix_agent.conf` and included `my.cnf`. What other settings do I need to configure, for Zabbix Agent to monitor MySQL Server?

Comment: What happens when you test a MySQL item using "zabbix_agentd -t ..."? Does it work? Are you using the correct agent configuration file (it should be zabbix_agentd.conf instead of zabbix_agent.conf)? What user parameter definitions have you included there?

Answer (score 7):

1. Check that your zabbix_server config file is including the /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/*.conf :

   ```
   vi /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
   ```

   (you will find at almost the end of file: Include =/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/*.conf)
2. Check where your zabbix_mysql config is :

   ```
   vim /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/userparameter_mysql.conf
   ```
3. If you'll find it for example: HOME=/var/lib/zabbix then create that directory if it does not exist:

   ```
   mkdir /var/lib/zabbix
   ```
4. change your position to that directory and create/edit .my.cnf file:

   ```
   cd /var/lib/zabbix
   vim .my.cnf
   ```

   add the following :

   ```
   [mysql]
   user=zabbix
   password=zabbix
   host=localhost

   [mysqladmin]
   user=zabbix
   password=zabbix
   host=localhost
   ```

   Then save.

I presume you already have a mysql username=zabbix and password=zabbix with all privileges.

Restart mysql:

```
    service mysqld restart
```

Now connect to your zabbix gui and check the values coming from mysql (Monitoring--> Latest data)

Comment: mysql restart is not needed

Comment: @MattBianco Instead it's required to restart the Zabbix agent, eh?

Comment: If anything need restarting, yes, it would be the `zabbix-agentd` process

Comment: Changing .my.cnf requires a restart

Comment: Changing .my.cnf does not require restarting anything. Changing agent config file requires restarting the agent. At no time MySQL should be restarted with the given steps.